# Can one be uninnovative?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, antonyms

Can one be *uninnovative*, or *un-innovative*? I'm looking for a direct antonym of the adjective *innovative*.

I see an entry at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uninnovative), but nothing at Merriam Webster ([innovative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovative), *[uninnovative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uninnovative)).

Comment: What about "outtovative"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Indeed, **un[-]innovative* does not exist, at least in formal usage. Depending on the context, any of the following could work:

- [*conventional*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1235773#m_en_us1235773)
- [*uninspired*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1302258#m_en_us1302258)
- [*unoriginal*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1302471#m_en_us1302471)
- [*stale*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1293769?rskey=F58ZQt&result=1#m_en_us1293769)
- [*tired*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1299020#m_en_us1299020)
- [*trite*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1300495#m_en_us1300495)

Comment: I think all these work best applied to things or concepts. If it's a person who's not innovative, I vote for *hidebound*.

Comment: But it does [exist](http://www.google.com/search?q=uninnovative&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), in real, honest-to-goodness books.  Heck, the word is even *in* the [Random House dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uninnovative) (as pointed out in the question).

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go against the grain and suggest that if 7-Up can create [the Un-cola](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQiZn9ZSQgM), you can pretty much attach the *un-* prefix to whatever you like, so long as you recognize that you may be stretching the boundaries a little. But, hey, boundaries are meant to be stretched, right? This doesn't seem to me like an egregious violation of any particular rule. And if I were to see *uninnovative* applied in a sentence, I would instantly understand what the writer meant and my reading flow would be uninterrupted.

Short answer: If *uninnovative* isn't a dictionary word (yet), I hereby nominate it as a useful innovation.

Comment: Fair enough, but using 7-Up as an authority on the English language isn't exactly reassuring! :S I agree, the word would be understood, albeit a bit awkward to pronounce.

Comment: @Noldorin: I think the point is that the un- prefix is very productive and can be added to almost anything, even if no one has ever done it before.

Comment: If one's level of innovation is mediocre is one not ununinnovative?

Comment: +1 *Uninnovative* has definitely been used before. Google Ngrams show a very low but non-zero level of use ever since 1960, which was when *innovative* first started being used widely.

Comment: Here are [examples of its use](http://www.google.com/search?q=uninnovative&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): "If uninnovative products could also gain commercial success...", "...perhaps being uninnovative will be the new definition of weak", etc.  No English speaker would read such sentences and be confused as to the meaning, and most of us would probably not even notice the word.

Answer (score 4):

Neither the OED nor Wiktionary have anything listed on *uninnovative* either, nor does the COCA have any entries listed. The BNC has one entry listed for 1991. Based on that evidence, I would conclude that *uninnovative* is not a word.

I would suggest *unimaginative* as an alternative.

Comment: I'm no native English speaker, but *unimaginative* sounds a bit pejorative - I like *conventional* more.

Answer (score 1):

How about *conservative* or *reactionary* (depending on how pejorative you want to be)?

Answer (score 0):

> Bureaucratic

if its an organization.

> Inflexible

if a person.